# Camera Output onto SceneKit Object

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm trying to use SceneKit in an application and am wanting to use images captured from an iPhone/iPad's camera (front or back) as a texture on an object in my `SCNScene`.

From everything that I can tell from the documentation as well as other questions here on StackOverflow, I should just be able to create a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` with an appropriate `AVCaptureSession` and have it "just work". Unfortunately, it does not.

I'm using a line of code like this:

`cubeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = layer`

Having the layer as the material seems to work because if I set the layer's `backgroundColor`, I see the background color, but the camera capturing does not appear to work. The layer is set up properly, because if I use the layer as a sublayer of the `SCNView` instead of on the object in the `SCNScene`, the layer appears properly in `UIKit`.

An example project can be found [here](https://github.com/EncodedNybble/SceneKitCameraMaterial).

You can use the `USE_FRONT_CAMERA` constant in `GameViewController.swift` to toggle between using front and back camera. You can use the `USE_LAYER_AS_MATERIAL` constant to toggle between using the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as the texture for a material or as a sub layer in the `SCNView`.

I've found a pretty hacky workaround for this using some OpenGL calls, but I'd prefer to have this code working as a more general and less fragile solution. Anyone know how to get this working properly on device? I've tried both iOS 8.0 and iOS 9.0 devices.